# iframe application cache not served to main page

Tags: iframe, html5-appcache, offline-caching, cache-manifest

In my web app I'm using multiple application cache resources: one manifest for the main page and 3 manifests for 3 different iframes - for content which is often updated.
My problem is : from the main page I call a html file which is in appcache of an iframe. This html file is served by the webserver and not by the appcache. If I put this html file in the main manifest it's well served by the appcache. It seems that the different appcaches are not sharing their resources: the main page always look for resources in the site.appcache and not in the iframes appcache.

How can I access the appcache of an iframe from the main page?

I looked for a response regarding the X-Frame options, but I didn't find something interesting, the main site and the iframes have the same origin.

Thanks